# ADO cannot access SQL Server XML type column using native client (SQLNCLI)

Tags: xml, delphi, sql-server-2005, ado, delphi-5

i am using ADO, and one of the *"native"* drivers (e.g. `SQLNCLI`, `SQLNCLI10`, `SQLNCLI11`) to connect to SQL Server (rather than the legacy `SQLOLEDB` driver).

ADO does not understand the `XML` SQL Server data type that the native drivers expose:

```
field: ADOField;

field := recordset.Fields.Items["SomeXmlColumn"];
```

Attempting to access `field.Value` throws an `EOleException`:

- **Source:** Microsoft Cursor Engine
- **ErrorCode:** 0x80040E21 (E_ITF_0E21)
- **Message:** Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value

The *native* client drivers (e.g. `SQLNCLI`, `SQLNCLI10`, `SQLNCLI11`) present an `Xml` data type to ADO as

```
field.Type_ = 141 //???
```

while the legacy `SQLOLEDB` driver presents an `Xml` data type to ADO as [adLongVarWChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675318.aspx), a unicode string:

```
field.Type_ = 203 //adLongVarWChar
```

And the `VARIANT` contained in `field.Value` is a [`WideString` (technically known as a `BSTR`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237865.aspx):

```
TVarData(field.Value).vtype = 8 //VT_BSTR
```

Seems to me that this is a bug in ADO (Windows 7 SP1), and not something i can fix.

How can i fix it?

## Bonus Reading

- [Delphi with SQL Server: OLEDB vs. Native Client drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082907/delphi-with-sql-server-oledb-vs-native-client-drivers)

Comment: Are you tried adding the [`DataTypeCompatibility`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx) keyword  to the connection string?

Comment: Phrase that in the form of an answer, RRUZ, and you have yourself an accept. (Because i have, and it fixes it). i'm gonna go steal credit on every other question on stack overflow where someone's getting `0x80040E21` when using ADO with SQL Server!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx) says

> To enable ADO to use new features of recent versions of SQL Server,
>   some enhancements have been made to the SQL Server Native Client OLE
>   DB provider which extends the core features of OLE DB. These
>   enhancements allow ADO applications to use newer SQL Server features
>   and to consume two data types introduced in SQL Server 2005: **xml** and
>   **udt**. These enhancements also exploit enhancements to the **varchar**,
>   **nvarchar**, and **varbinary** data types. SQL Server Native Client adds the
>   SSPROP_INIT_DATATYPECOMPATIBILITY initialization property to the
>   DBPROPSET_SQLSERVERDBINIT property set for use by ADO applications so
>   that the new data types are exposed in a way compatible with ADO. In
>   addition, the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB provider also defines a
>   new connection string keyword named **DataTypeCompatibility** that is set
>   in the connection string.

So to enable the use of new SQL Server features in the Native Client, you need to add the following keywords in the connection string:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11
DataTypeCompatibility=80
```

where [**DataTypeCompatibility**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx):

> Specifies the mode of data type handling to use. Recognized values are "0" for provider data types and "80" for SQL Server 2000 data types.